# How to render Module Federation Component inside of my test DOM?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, react-testing-library, webpack-module-federation

I'm writing Jest tests for a React.js application and using the React Testing Library. My application imports module federation components.
I need to find a way to test the app with these federated components. I can't just mock the federated components because I need to have them rendered in the test DOM.

I tried to follow the suggestions from Zack Jackson in his YouTube video ([Federated Unit Tests?!](https://youtu.be/Ak2Rms-CFmM?si=s-w0aMC93ym3TG-u)), but I don’t understand how to implement them in my project.

**Here is code for my test **

```
describe('DropDown Selector Tests', () => {

    test('Should render all passed-in dropdowns', () => {
        render(<DropDownContainer dropdowns={dropdowns} />);       
        screen.debug(); // print dom tree 
        dropdowns.forEach((drop_down, index) => {
            const element = screen.getByTestId(`dropdown-select-${index}`);
            expect(document.body.contains(element)).toBe(true);

            const firtItem: DropdownSelectItemProps = drop_down.items[0] as DropdownSelectItemProps
            const firstLabelText: string = firtItem.label as string; 
            const dropDown = screen.getByLabelText(firstLabelText);
            expect(document.body.contains(dropDown)).toBe(true);
        });

    });
})
```

**My DropDownContainer container element**

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import {
    DropdownSelect,
    DropdownSelectProps
} from 'federated/Components';
import './DropDownContainer.scss';

export interface DropDownContainerProps {
    /** list of drop-downs*/
    dropdowns: DropdownSelectProps[]
}


/**
 * This component accepts a list of drop-downs and organizes them within a responsive frame.
 * @param props
 * @returns
 */
const DropDownContainer = (props: DropDownContainerProps) => {

    const { dropdowns } = props;

    return (
        <div className='sort-container' data-testid='dropdown-container'>                   
            {
                dropdowns.map((d, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div data-testid={`dropdown-select-${index}`} key={index} >
                            <DropdownSelect                                  
                                key={index}
                                className='sort'
                                {...d} />
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default DropDownContainer;
```

**This is how the test rendered DOM **

```
    <body>
      <div>
        <div
          class="sort-container"
          data-testid="dropdown-container"
        >
          <div
            data-testid="dropdown-select-0"
          />
          <div
            data-testid="dropdown-select-1"
          />
          <div
            data-testid="dropdown-select-2"
          />
          <div
            data-testid="dropdown-select-3"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

As you can see, the  DropdownSelect is not rendered.

If the the DropdownSelect would have been rendered, the component DOM would have looked like this:

```
<div class="sort-container">
<div id="sui-dropdown-select-0" class="sui-dropdown-select sort" aria-label="sui-dropdown-select-0">
Sale Type:<select style="display: none;">
        <option id="Sale Type1" value="Sale Type1">Sale Type1</option>
        <option id="Sale Type2" value="Sale Type2">Sale Type2</option>
    </select>
    <div class="sui-dropdown-select-nice-select sui-dropdown-select-right">
        <span class="sui-dropdown-select-current">Show All</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sui-dropdown-select-1" class="sui-dropdown-select sort" aria-label="sui-dropdown-select-1">
Market:<select style="display: none;">
        <option id="West" value="West">p</option>
        <option id="East" value="East">East</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**My webpack config: **

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { FederatedTypesPlugin } = require('@module-federation/typescript');
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = webpack.container;
const federationConfig = require('./federationConfig');
const package = require('../package.json');
const { NativeFederationTestsHost, NativeFederationTestsRemote } = require('@module-federation/native-federation-tests/webpack');

// Set the homepage differently based on dev or production
const homepage = process.env.HOMEPAGE ?? `/${(package.homepage ?? '')}`.replace("//", "/");


module.exports = {
  experiments: { topLevelAwait: true },
  entry: {
    main: path.join(__dirname, '../src/index.ts'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        // inline svg assets
        // custom.d.ts definition
        {
            test: /\.svg/,
            type: 'asset/inline'
          },
        // load typescript
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin(federationConfig),
    new FederatedTypesPlugin({
      federationConfig,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'public/index.html',
        title: 'internalbilling',
      filename: 'index.html',
      chunks: ['main'],
        publicPath: homepage,
    }),
      new NativeFederationTestsRemote({ federationConfig }),
      new NativeFederationTestsHost({ federationConfig })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js', '.json'],
  },
};
```

**My federationConfig **:

```
const dependencies = require('../package.json').dependencies;


module.exports = {
    name: 'myapp'.toLowerCase(),

  
    remotes: {
        federated: `federated@https://media.CompanyA.com/cdn/js/CompanyAUI/remoteEntry.js`
    },
    filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
    
    shared: {
        ...dependencies,
        'react': {
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: dependencies['react'],
        },
        'react-dom': {
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: dependencies['react-dom'],
        },
    },
};
```

Jest setting from package.json

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "ts-jest",
  "clearMocks": true,
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "@mf-types"
  ],
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "mjs",
    "cjs",
    "jsx",
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "json",
    "node"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^companyA/Components/(.*)$": "./@mf-types/companyA/Components.d.ts"
  },
  "reporters": [
    "default"
  ],
  "rootDir": "./ClientApp",
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
  "globals": {
    "transform": {
      "^.\\.scss$": "jest-scss-transform",
      "^.\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "verbose": true
  },
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.scss$": "jest-scss-transform",
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
    "<rootDir>/configs/jest.setup.ts"
  ]
}
```

- I  tried to use mocks, but It doesn't work because I need my test to see what federated component renders
- I tried to set up my project to render federated components, but I failed

Comment: Can you show what `dropdowns` prop (<DropDownContainer dropdowns={dropdowns} />) contains in your test?

Comment: here is the test DOM output of <DropDownContainer dropdowns={dropdowns} /> component 'code'     <body>
      <div>
        <div
          class="sort-container"
          data-testid="dropdown-container"
        >
          <div
            data-testid="dropdown-select-0"
          />
          <div
            data-testid="dropdown-select-1"
          />
          <div
            data-testid="dropdown-select-2"
          />
          <div
            data-testid="dropdown-select-3"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>'code'

Comment: @collab-with-tushar-raj, I edited my question and added hrml that I need to be generated by the test DOM, hopefully it answers your question.